# Excel 2016 Scatter Plot - wrong position on x-axis if cell with formula is blanc

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I am trying to chart in Excel a table that is built conditionally.

The table on the left comes from the table form the right and leaves cells blank if the corresponding ones on the other tables aren't numbers.

[image]

However, if I try to extend the range, in order to include the cells that have a formula but are blank, the x-axis behaves in a bizarre way and the x values will be 1,2,3 instead of the given ones.

[image]

I guess it doesn't consider numeric values any more as numbers and just orders the items on the x-axis.

What can I do to make it work properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind showing a dot at 0,0 then this works. If your reference data are not numbers, then use 0....

```
Cell C3 formula: =IF(ISNUMBER(F3),F3,0)
```

Drag it where needed.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an empty string in your formula, return a NA value

Formula: `=IF(ISNUMBER(E6);E6;NA())`

[image]

If you need to hide those values, use conditional format ([see this](https://excel-example.com/other-tutorial/how-to-hide-error-values))

Let me know if it works